# codeigniter input fields with same name

Tags: codeigniter, validation, select, radio-button

sorry  if its a stupid question but i need a bit of a help.

I made a signup form, and i would like to people select 2 phone numbers.

If i select hungarian a hungarian phone type input slides down, if he selects ukraine than an ukraine phone input type slides down.

here is the html

```
    <input type='text' name='telefon' id='magyar' class='input_title' value='<?php echo set_value('telefon'); ?>' />

    <input type='text' name='telefon' id='ukran' class='input_title' value='<?php echo set_value('telefon'); ?>' />

    <div class='hiba'><?php echo form_error('telefon'); ?></div>    

magyar = hingarian 
ukran = ukraine
telefon = phone
telo_tipus = phoe type
```

my problem is the validation, if i select hungarian and fill it out it says i need to add a phone number but if i select ukraine its ok

here is the validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('telefon', 'Telefon', 'required|callback_hasznalt_telefon');
```

could please someone point out what im missing with the validation?

i tried with na=telefon[] but in that case the validation wont work

the callback only validates if the phone is taken thats ok but here it is

```
function hasznalt_telefon()
    {
        $telefon = trim($this->input->post('telefon'));

        $query  = $this->db->query(' SELECT telefon FROM felhasznalok WHERE telefon = "'.$telefon.'" ');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('hasznalt_telefon', 'Ez a telefonszám  már használatban van '); 
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return true;    
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need to post your callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codeigniter code is fine, but your html/javascript is what needs to change.

Instead of having two input fields with the same name (which the php script will only read the last one, btw), you should make a select field that changes what input type slides down from the 'telefon' field.

I'm not sure what javascript you are using, but in jquery you can have the the input field event bound on selection from the select field.

If you need more specific guidance for this, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

```
<select id="telefon_type">
    <option>Telefon Type</option>
    <option value="magyar">Magyar</option>
    <option value="ukran">Ukran</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" disabled />

$("#telefon_type").bind("change", function() {
    $("#telefon").removeAttr("disabled");

    if ($(this).val() == "magyar") {
        $("#telefon").bind("focus",function() {
            // onfocus event for #telefon for magyar
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == "ukran") {
        $("#telefon").bind("focus",function() {
            // onfocus event for #telefon for ukran
        });
    } else {
        $("#telefon").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#telefon").val('');
    }

});
```

Please note: I have not tested this code. The general idea behind it is that the filter you are running for the telefon field changes based on your selection of the select field.

Comment: first thanks for spending yout time on my question, yes a more more specific anwser would be great

Comment: love ya, it worked, modified it with a phone number plugin, thank you so much, feel a bit dumb thouh, and thans for spending time on my question

Comment: Sometimes you need another set of eyeballs. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has beeen already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428775/am-i-doing-this-wrong-or-is-there-a-bug-in-the-codeigniter-form-validation-libra). Phil Sturgeon is working on that issue, so you can try to use the development branch of CI from github.

Comment: I don't think this is the OP's issue. OP's issue is that he has two fields of the same name and only wants the input from either field. Since PHP (and thus codeigniter) will only read the last field named 'telefon', codeigniter is only reading the field with id='ukran' for validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only ONE telephon number (depends on nationality) I think it would be simplier when you use only ONE input field and write its value to database (or do anything what you want). Or is there any reason to use two input fields?